# x86 variable alignment in memory without struct using C

Tags: c

I use C on a x86 based CPU. 
There are lot of articles that explain the alignment of variables in the memory by using structs and #pragma pack directives. That's all nice as long you are willing to use structs.

I am looking for a way to ensure the alignment of variables in the memory (order and size) **WITHOUT using a struct**.

Ist there any way to do this?

In the form of

```
#pragma (push)
**#pragma "anyalignment directive"**
int a;
byte b;
long l;
#pragma (pop)
```

Comment: The compiler normally take care of memory alignment. To do something like the one you want you must use special compiler directive to **qualify** the variable alignment. They can be `__declspec` for MSVC or `__attribute__` for GCC.

Comment: **Why do you ask?** You should explain!

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: You can use `__attribute__` for GCC. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

Comment: The reason is that i want to create a kind of backup (snapshot) of a bunch of variables by just copying an area in the memory (start address and size), without takeing care what kind of variables are in this area. The same code runs also on a ARM in a very time sensitive environment. accessing the variables via a struct is not an option because we are not sure how the compiler (on the ARM) translates this.  In the x86 environment, the execution time is not so critical.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GCC or Clang, it's like this:

```
int x __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

In MSVC:

```
__declspec(align(16)) int x;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx

Answer (score 1):

With GCC attributes, you could ensure the alignment of each variable like this:

```
int a __attribute__((aligned(16)));
byte b __attribute__((aligned(2)));
long l __attribute__((aligned(32)));
```

But then, why would you need that? The compiler is free to reorder the declarations in a way that it sees fit (unlike struct members, there is no requirement that the variables should reside adjacently, or even be in memory).

Also, crossing the boundaries of these variables with pointers will result in undefined behaviour. You cannot assume that `b` will come right after `a` and that there will be a gap of a definite size between them.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I want to backup an entire memory region (e.g. imagine i do have a statemachine with about 80 variables. now i want to be able to take a snapshot of all these variables and restore the statemachine to the very same state on a alter time). of course i can bakckup each and every variable by it's name, but this is not very convenient in terms of maintenance /extensions.

Comment: further i could use structs, that would work for the x86 environment. but the very same code runs also in a high realtime environment (ARM), a struct has the risk of additional overhead when accessing the members in it (depending on how the compiler handles this).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to enforce allocation order in memory without using `struct`. You would have to resort to non-standard syntax to allocate the variables at fixed addresses.

As for alignment, you can force a wider alignment than the default one, by using the standard C `_Alignas` keyword. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// force 16 byte alignment:
int _Alignas(16) x;
int _Alignas(16) y;
int _Alignas(16) z;

int main (void)
{
  printf("%p\n", (void*)&x);
  printf("%p\n", (void*)&y);
  printf("%p\n", (void*)&z);
  return 0;
}
```

Output for me on gcc/mingw in Windows is

```
0000000000407970
0000000000407990
0000000000407980
```

The alignment requirement of 16 bytes is satisfied, but as we can see this does not affect the allocation order.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I need to ensure that all variables have the same order on each compile, hence this is might not working for me.

Comment: @J.Ens Simple: use a struct.

Comment: Hi Lundin, yes with a struckt it all works fine. but i am searching a way without using a struct...

Comment: @J.Ens I know. See the first sentence of this answer. If you are looking for a non-standard solution, then you need to edit your question and tell which specific compiler that is used.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of missed that part. I am using the Visual Studio 2012 compiler for x86 architecture